# Can I set a time-out for auto-mounted shares that are unavailable?

Tags: mount, nfs, share, sshfs, autofs

I am using autofs to mount an NFS remote share at boot so it's mounted when I'm logged in. If the remote share is down, I can't login to Ubuntu, it hangs after entering my password.

Any way to set a timeout on the remote share so it forgets about mounting an unavailable share after N seconds and lets me login?

If not with NFS, then with SSHFS?

Answer (score 1):

After some searching, I found your answer in the Centos documentation.

In autofs, when you define your mount, you can set options in `auto.master`, including a time out, in the third field as an options

Example:

```
/misc   /etc/auto.misc --timeout 60
```

See http://www.centos.org/docs/4/4.5/System_Administration_Guide/Mounting_NFS_File_Systems-Mounting_NFS_File_Systems_using_autofs.html